# ubuntu upgrade crash

Tags: 12.04

Every time I try to update my Ubuntu it says packages update failed and this came:

```
upinstallArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
E: Could not open file descriptor -1
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/initramfs-tools-bin_0.103ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/klibc-utils_2.0.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libklibc_2.0.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/dmsetup_2%%3a1.02.77-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libdevmapper1.02.1_2%%3a1.02.77-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/ntpdate_1%%3a4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu2.14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm2_2.4.56-1~ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/mountall_2.53_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libldap-2.4-2_2.4.31-1+nmu2ubuntu8_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/librtmp0_2.4+20121230.gitdf6c518-1_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libcurl3-gnutls_7.35.0-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libusb-1.0-0_2%%3a1.0.17-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/ntfs-3g_1%%3a2013.1.13AR.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Prior errors apply to
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message say `LANGUAGE = (unset), LC_ALL = (unset),`, it say the language is not configured. So try to install language package. For English you can use "sudo apt-get install language-pack-en". After installing he language try to run upgrade

Comment: thanx for the help but i actually had to restore my system and then i did a clean update to 14.04 lts